# Serialize and Deserialize trees using left/right brackets

Tags: algorithm

Trees here have n nodes(not a binary tree!)

I was trying to implement the idea of the following

```
     1       (1((2)(3)(4)))
   /  \  \
  2    3  4
(2)  (3)  (4)
```

I have my initial algorithm drafted as below. The serialization func is to return `(`root`(`children nodes`))` on each call. The deserialization func is to construct root and its children nodes from parentheses

Can someone see why the implementation was incorrect?

```py
    def serialize(self, root):
        """Encodes a tree to a single string.

        :type root: Node
        :rtype: str
        """
        if not root: return ''

        if not root.children: return '(' + str(root.val) + ')'

        res = "("
        for child in root.children:
            res += self.serialize(child)
        res += ')'  # ((2)(3)(4))
        return '(' + str(root.val) + res + ')' # (1((2)(3)(4)))

    def deserialize(self, data):
        """Decodes your encoded data to tree.

        :type data: str
        :rtype: Node
        """
        #       ^
        # 0 1 2 3 ...
        # ( 1 ( ( 2 )(3) ) )
        if not data: return None
        val = data[1]
        root = Node(int(val))
        root.children = []
        left = 0
        start = 3 # choose 3 as shown above(skip all parenthesis until seeing the children)

        for i in range(3, len(data) - 2): #skip last parentheses for the same reason
            if data[i] == '(': left += 1
            if data[i] == ')':
                left -= 1
                if left == 0:
                    child = self.deserialize(data[start:i + 1])
                    root.children.append(child)
                    start = i + 1

        return root
```

Comment: What exactly is incorrect with the implementation? Can you show us a case where it breaks?

Comment: Btw, you probably don't need the first enclosing parentheses of `((2)(3)(4))`, as you skip them in your parser anyways